# how to unbind data from view? - knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

I have some data bound to the View. Have used cleanNode to unbind the data- and clear the view. Here the is the jsfiddle for the same: http://jsfiddle.net/FENuV/26/

The code for the same is below:
View:

```
    <div id="QdetailsDiv">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div><span>Sold to Account</span></div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="txtSoldToAccount" data-bind="value:SoldToAccount"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div><span>Job Name</span></div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="txtQDJobName"  data-bind="value:jobName"/></div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <input type="button" value="unbind" id="unbindbutton"></input>
</div>
```

View model:

```
    QuoteDetails = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.SoldToAccount = ko.observable();
    self.jobName = ko.observable();
};

function SimpleSearchResults() {
    var self = this;
    self.index = ko.observable();
    self.quoteDetailsObj = ko.observable(new QuoteDetails()); 
    self.productDetailsArrObj = ko.observableArray([]); 

    self.BindDataToQuotesDetailVM = function (SimpleSearchResultsOb) {
        var self= this;
        //SimpleSearchResultsOb['SoldToAccount']('SoldToAccount test');
       SimpleSearchResultsOb.SoldToAccount = "SoldToAccount test";
        SimpleSearchResultsOb.jobName = ko.observable("jobName test");

        ko.applyBindings(SimpleSearchResultsOb, document.getElementById("QdetailsDiv"));
    };    
};

function QuoteSimpleSearchVM() {

    var self = this;
    self.simpleSearchResultsArray = ko.observableArray([]);

    var SimpleSearchResultsObj= new SimpleSearchResults();
    SimpleSearchResultsObj.index=ko.observable("1");
    self.simpleSearchResultsArray.push(SimpleSearchResultsObj);    

    var SimpleSearchResultsObj2= new SimpleSearchResults();
    SimpleSearchResultsObj2.index=ko.observable("2");
    self.simpleSearchResultsArray.push(SimpleSearchResultsObj2);    

};
 var obj= new QuoteSimpleSearchVM();
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#unbindbutton").click(function(){
        var element = $('#QdetailsDiv')[0];
        ko.cleanNode(element);
    });    

    ko.utils.arrayForEach(obj.simpleSearchResultsArray(), function (SimpleSearchResultsObj) {             
                if (SimpleSearchResultsObj.index() === "2") {
                    SimpleSearchResultsObj.BindDataToQuotesDetailVM(this);
                }
            });
});
```

On cleanNode, the data is not cleared from the view. 
Can anyone help me with the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not supposed to be cleared.

Comment: In the about example, not able to unbind the viewmodel from view using cleanNode. I want to clear the view on unbind. How to achieve this?

Comment: You cannot "clear" the view using cleanNode. What do you want to do? Your problem could probably be solved by using a cleaner solution.

Comment: In the example: http://jsfiddle.net/FENuV/26/
 on click of unbind, i want to clear the view data and unbind the view model from the view. How can this be achieved?